# Name list of dataframes based on values in rows

Tags: r, subset, lapply

I have created a list of dataframes from this dataframe `df`

```
structure(list(ï..Name = structure(c(5L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 13L, 
7L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 11L), .Label = c("Alex", "Alice", 
"Greg", "Jay", "Jim", "Mick", "Mike", "Patrick", "Reese", "Sarah", 
"Simon", "Sue", "Timmy"), class = "factor"), Partner = structure(c(7L, 
9L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alan", 
"Alex", "Britney", "Dalton", "Jeff", "Mary", "Peggy", "Percy", 
"Sue", "Susan", "Tara"), class = "factor"), Group1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), class = "factor"), Group2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Alpha", 
"Bravo ", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Gamma"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

using this code

```
list_df=df %>% 
  split(group_indices_(df, .dots =c("Group1","Group2")))
```

I am first trying to name each of the dataframe objects by combining the factor inside `Group1` plus `Group2`. Then I am trying to and subset each of the dataframes in the `list_df` to only have the `Name` column in column 1 and `Partner` in column 2.

I have been able to subset the dataframes by doing this

```
sub_toy=lapply(list_df, select,ï..Name, Partner)
```

What I cannot figure out is how to actually name the list of objects inside before I subset so I know what group combination each of the dataframes belongs to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for any of the following

```
split(df[1:2], df[3:4], TRUE)

split(df[1:2], do.call(paste, df[3:4]))
```

Comment: the second answer looks great, but is there a way I can select by column names? For example instead of `df[1:2]` could i somehow index like `df["ï..Name", "Partner"]`? I know that code won't actually work, but is there a way to do something like that with just column names

Comment: @M76 yes, you could combine the names using `c` like `split(df[c("ï..Name", "Partner")], do.call(paste, df[3:4]))` and it would return the same result.

Comment: It works! However, can you explain a bit more of what the code is doing? Just for my own edification

Comment: @M76 `do.call(paste,...)` just pastes the rows together into one string. and uses that as the splitting factor

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution I came up with. Hopefully gets what you are looking for:

```
n <-  names(list_df)

for(ii in 1:length(list_df)) {
    n[ii] = paste(as.character(unique(list_df[[ii]][[3]])),
    "_",
    as.character(unique(list_df[[ii]][[4]])), 
    sep = "")
}

names(list_df) <- n

l <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {x[,-c(3,4)]}) #or your function call, too
```